# How to silent Django's warning for 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, suppress-warnings

I am working with Django Rest Framework, and each time there is a request resulting in 405 Method Not Allowed, an annoying warning will be printed in the console. I wonder if I can opt to silent this warning, since it is rather not helpful in my settings.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad Yes, I am. Is that the reason? If it is, is there any way I can suppress it, so when I run tests, they don't come up bothering.

Comment: Maybe try changing log level or something ? Ideally, I would have tried fixing those warnings instead of suppressing them.

Comment: No, those warnings are there because I had some tests to explicitly access some recourses using forbidden methods, and I am using the assertions with status codes to check that, so it does not make things more helpful to see those warnings in the console.

Comment: Had the same issues with tests and suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377231) helped.